# Getting the image from fingerprint device using C#

Tags: c#, fingerprint

I am using C# to implement JKFinger SDK into our office project and I am new to C#. There are two methods in SDK, `PrintImageAt()` which is drawing image into `PictureBox` And `GetFingerImage()` get the last captured image by device in bmp format.

```
Graphics g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
int dc = g.GetHdc().ToInt32();
axZKFPEngX1.PrintImageAt(dc, 0, 0, axZKFPEngX1.ImageWidth, axZKFPEngX1.ImageHeight);
object obj = null;
axZKFPEngX1.GetFingerImage(ref obj);
```

Now I want to store the captured image into database. The `PictureBox` is displaying the images but not initializing with it. For getting image from `PictureBox` is returning null. And for `GetFingerPrint(ref obj)` is returning an object but can't be converted to Bitmap. I want to know how to get that image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetFingerPrint(ref obj)` Is returning `System.Byte[]` Object.

```
axZKFPEngX1.GetFingerImage(ref obj);
byte[] data = (byte[])obj;
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data);
Image image = Image.FromStream(ms);
```